# Wrong computatation inside the nested loops

Tags: java

The goal of the code is to find the numbers that add up to the `targetNumber`. For example, if the `targetNumber = 9` then the code should get the first two occuring indexes of the numbers that add up to the `targetNumber`. When I run my code, the output looks like the following:

```
The indexes are 10 and 1
```

What's wrong with the logic of the code? Thanks in advance!

```
public class TwoSum {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] myArray = {1, 6, 43, 22, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 3};
        int targetNumber = 9;
        int index1 = 0;;
        int index2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++){
                if(myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber){
                    index1 = i;
                    index2 = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The indexes are " + index1 + " and " + index2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are expecting the output to be `1` and `7`?

Comment: Since the index is zero-based, index 10 and 1 are referring to the last '3' (index 10) and the first '6' (index 1).
It is by far not an elegant solution, but they are adding up to '9'. So what's the problem you need help with? That it is not using the first occurrence of '3' (i.e. index 7)?

Comment: @user2341963, `0` (1) and `8` (7). I have to print only indexes of the numbers.

Comment: Looks like @Shar1er80 has what you're looking for if that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're expecting indexes 0 and 8 (values 1 and 8).  The problem is that your `break` statement only breaks from the inner loop and not the outer loop.  You need to use a flag to know that you also should break from the outer loop.  Also consider printing a message if no match is found.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] myArray = {1, 6, 43, 22, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 3};
    int targetNumber = 9;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    boolean stop = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length && !stop; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length && !stop; j++) {
            if (myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber) {
                stop = true;
                index1 = i;
                index2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stop 
            ? "The indexes are " + index1 + " and " + index2
            : "No match found");
}
```

Or just print the results inside the inner loop and use a `return` instead of a `break`.  This way you don't have to use a flag.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] myArray = {1, 6, 43, 22, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 3};
    int targetNumber = 9;

    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++){
            if(myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber){
                System.out.println("The indexes are " + i + " and " + j);
                return;
            }
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

Results:

```
The indexes are 0 and 8
```

Comment: Great answer, @Shar1er80. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you break, you only break out of the inner loop, so instead of printing out 1 and then 10, the outer loop continues, terminating naturally, and resulting in the print out of index 10 then index 1.

An interesting result of this is that your code essentially finds the *last* pair of numbers that sum to `targetNumber`, rather than the first. If you made your for loops count down instead of up, the code should spit out the correct values, although it wouldn't be very efficient...

Comment: But how to break out of both loops immediately when the indexes are found? I tried to `break` after the inner-loop but showed `dead-code`, @Aderis

Comment: @John check my answer on how to break from the outer loop properly.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code a little cleaner; that is, entirely foregoing the `break` statement, you should introduce a boolean variable called `found` to your loops. This way, you can break out of both of them more intuitively if you find your first match.

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length && !found; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length && !found; j++){
        if(myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber){
            found = true;
            index1 = i;
            index2 = j;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("The indexes are " + index1 + " and " + index2);
```

If you're ever curious about what other pairs of numbers add up to your target, create a `Pair<T>` class which can store that kind of info.  You wouldn't break out of any loops as you're essentially bruteforcing the entire thing.

```
class Pair<T> {
    final T firstValue;
    final T secondValue;


    Pair(T firstValue, T secondValue) {
        this.firstValue = firstValue;
        this.secondValue = secondValue;
    }

    public T getFirstValue() {
        return firstValue;
    }

    public T getSecondValue() {
        return secondValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + firstValue + ", " + secondValue + "}";
    }
}

// later in your code


List<Pair<Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++){
        if(myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber){
            pairs.add(new Pair<>(i, j));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("The indexes are " + pairs);
```

The above prints out:

```
The indexes are [{0, 8}, {1, 7}, {1, 10}, {5, 7}, {5, 10}, {7, 1}, {7, 5}, {10, 1}, {10, 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The break statement is breaking the inner loop but not the outer one. So its getting the last result of 3 and 6 instead of the 1 and 8.

A more appropriate way may be:

```
    bool found=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(!found){
            for(int j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++){
                if(myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber){ 
                    index1 = i; index2 = j;               
                    found=true; 
                    break; 
} } }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that are wrong with your code:

1. According to specification, you want to find first matching indices, while
   you actually are finding last. That happens because `break` breaks only inner loop. The easy fix is to use label (`outer:`). Although the cleaner approach would be using dedicated method to do the search and `return` the first matched value.
2. You are checking pairs of indices twice and also checking pairs of the same index. The idiomatic approach that eliminates this redundancy is to start nested loop from the current value of the index of the outer loop (`j = i`) or (`j = i + 1`) if you don't want to have pairs of the same index (i, i).
3. You are not considering the situation when no matching index is found. In this case you will show that (0,0) is the result.

Here is your code fixed:

```
        public static class TwoSum {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[] myArray = {1, 6, 43, 22, 4, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 3};
                int targetNumber = 9;
                int index1 = -1;
                int index2 = -1;

                outer:
                for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
                        if (myArray[i] + myArray[j] == targetNumber) {
                            index1 = i;
                            index2 = j;
                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (index1 >= 0) {
                    System.out.println("The indexes are " + index1 + " and " + index2 + "(Values " + myArray[index1] +
                            " and " + myArray[index2] + ")");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not found");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: By the way, there is more efficient approach to this problem ( O(n), without nested loop). I can share, if you are interested.